# Help with a linear algebra question (transition matrices)

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I can't seem to figure out to do part b). Is the correct procedure to multiply $[V]_s$ by $P$? Can anyone tell me the appropriate procedure?

Answer (score 1):

The transition matrix $P$ from $B'$ to $B$ denoted sometimes by $P_{B\to B'}$ *(Notice that the notation is contrary to the apparent meaning)* is the matrix which acts on a vector relative to the basis $B$ to give a vector relative to the basis $B'$ hence

$$[v]_B=P^{-1}[v]_{B'}$$
and
$$[T(v)]_B= P^{-1}A[v]_{B'}$$